# OData/Jaydata where...in query

Tags: javascript, rest, odata, jaydata

I'm building a SPA that communicates with a tomcat server that exposes REST services using the Odata protocol. The queries are created using the [Jaydata](http://jaydata.org/) framework.

I need to make a query like this:

```
SELECT * from category where category.id in (1223,1001....)
```

currently  I build it with OR:

```
  $filter=(((((((category/id eq 1062) or (category/id eq 1061)) or (category/id eq 1063)) ...
```

Is there a way to change it to where...in query instead of OR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
context.Categories.filter("it.id in ids", { ids: yourarraywithids} ).toArray()
```